# Рекурсия, StackOverflowError

Tags: java, рекурсия

Подскажите, почему строка `return getMoney().getAmount();` метода `getAmount` класса `A` возвращает программу в метод `getMoney()` класса `B`?

Что вообще означает `getMoney().getAmount()`?

Как `getMoney()` может вызывать другой какой-то метод? Разве `getMoney()` это не метод?

```
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new B().getAmount());
    }

    public static abstract class A {
        abstract A getMoney();

        public Object getAmount() {
            return getMoney().getAmount();
        }
    }

    public static class B extends A {
        private double amount = 123d;

        public B getMoney() {
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ну getMoney() возвращает объект, у которого есть метод getAmount.

Answer (score 1):

Изначально вызывается метод `getAmount` у класса `B`

```
new B().getAmount()
```

т.к у него нет своего метода (метод, который физически был бы определён в этом классе) `getAmount`, но он наследник класса `A`, то по принципу наследования вызывается метод родителя (т.к. подификатор доступа `public`, а не `private`, значит метод доступен в наследниках). В нём вызывается `getMoney()`. Этот метод уже определён в классе `B` и он возвращает ссылку на экземпляр своего класса (`this`). У экземпляра класса есть методы есессно. И так как `getMoney()` вернул объект `B`, то дальше конструкция `.getAmount()` абсолютно легальна и вызывает метод опять у объекта с типом `B`. Который запускает всё по кругу опять

Answer (score 1):

> *Что вообще означает `getMoney().getAmount()?`*
> *Как `getMoney()` может вызывать другой какой-то метод? Разве `getMoney()` это не метод?*

По своему определению абстрактный метод `getMoney()` возвращает ссылку на экземпляр класса `A`, и уже для этого экземпляра вызывается метод `getMoney()`.  Проблема именно в реализации метода `getAmount()` в классе `A`, где вызовы зацикливаются.

Для разрыва зацикливания нужно переопределить (override) метод `getAmount()` в классе `B` следующим образом:

```java
public static class B extends A {
    private double amount = 123d;

    @Override
    public B getMoney() {
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public Number getAmount() {
        return this.amount;
    }
}
```

Тогда результат вызова будет корректный:

```
123.0
```